# Как правильно сделать дженерик? Java

Tags: java, generics

У меня есть абстрактный класс **BaseCommand**, который имеет в себе абстрактный метод *execute*. У меня есть два типа команд: **SlashCommand** & **Command**. (Они тоже абстрактные и наследуются от BaseCommand), они оба должны реализовать метод *execute*, но у них разные эвенты. **SlashCommand** -> **SlashCommandInteractionEvent**, **Command** -> **CommandEvent**. Так вот, в чем заключается вопрос, как мне сделать, чтобы *execute* мог ожидать два типа эвента? Это возможно сделать через дженерики?

Я просто не хочу писать два раза метод, но с разными эвентами, как на коде ниже

```
public abstract class BaseCommand

{
  protected abstract void execute(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event);

  protected abstract void execute(CommandEvent event); // Hет эвента, пока что

  // Хочу что-то типо такого, думаю, вы поняли
  protected abstract <T> void execute(T event);

}
```

Comment: а у event-ов есть общий предок или общий интерфейс?

Comment: SlashCommandInteractionEvent - это эвент из либы, а CommandEvent - кастомный

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BaseCommand<T extends BaseCommand>    
{

  protected abstract void execute(T event);

}
```

Думаю, что то типа такого должно быть.

Comment: event в методе execute не является "расширением" класса BaseCommand, это совершенно другой класс.